# Getting these elements/classes next to each other in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm sure that this is gonna be pretty easy to debug but regardless I've been having issues for quite some time.
I'm trying to get these two elements next to each other. It's a really simple idea.
[It's literally just me trying to put two boxes next to each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj89I.png)

And I've done this before but I guess I could really use someone to help debug my code right now.

The way it's written...

```
aside.left {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(8, 78, 7, 0.7);
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }

section.right {
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(198, 207, 214);
}
```

So my rationale is to try to convert these two elements into inline-blocks since they both are block types. And then I try to float one ot the right and one to the left.
But this isn't working, and it's only making the elements stack on top of each other.

How do I solve this probably pretty simple error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go with ***display:inline-block***.
You just have to remember, that block elements (div,section,aside, etc. are per default block elements) always have 100% width, unless you change it in your stylesheet.

https://jsfiddle.net/ay4d8hau/

In my example I used percent sized elements.

```
aside.left {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(8, 78, 7, 0.7);
    width: 20%;
    /* width:200px; */
    text-align: center;
  }

section.right {
    float: right;
    width:80%;
    /* width:600px; -> will only fit next to each other if the viewport is bigger than 800px */
    background-color: rgb(198, 207, 214);
}
```

For pixel widths:
If you want to use pixel widths, the sum of both widths have to be smaller than the viewport to display both elements next to each other. If not, the elements will stack on top of each other (see my code example).

```
aside.left {
    width:200px;
  }

section.right {
    width:600px;
}
```

-> Elements will not stack if the viewport size is bigger than 800px (e.g. 801px).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to float anything, you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get the layout you're looking for without having to worry about floats, clears, and minimal math. Just wrap the elements with a parent container to add the flex property to.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/beepye/pen/KMzZjr

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

aside.left,
section.right {
  border:2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:200px;
  padding:20px;
}

aside.left {
  background: rgba(8, 78, 7, 0.7);
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 0;
}

section.right {
    width:80%;
    background-color: rgb(198, 207, 214);
}
```

There's full support for current browsers:

[image: Flexbox browser compatibility]

But if IE is a concern you may need a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You can not float `display: inline-block;` elements, they align correctly as that. make them block instead and keep the float.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx63bmg5/)

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.clearfix {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  background-color: deeppink;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your section.right ? If you want something like the image you can do something like this (roughly). I personally prefer to float both of my containers to the left because when the break they will end up on the left side (natural flow of elements, unless you are doing RTL).

```
aside.left {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(8, 78, 7, 0.7);
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
  }

section.right {
    width: 75%;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(198, 207, 214);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfcv4w96/1/

Either `flex` or `table` displays would solve your problem.

Using `table` with a block element wrapper:

```
.table.wrap {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table.left,
.table.right {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

And using `flex` (still need a wrapper):

```
.flex.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

Besides browser support ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)), the main difference would be the collapsed border with `table` display.